# File size is too large Superpowered Library Recorder

Tags: java, android, c++, audio-processing, superpowered

I'm trying to record low latency audio through this superpowered library. [superpowered](https://github.com/ryardley/superpowered/tree/master/Examples_Android/SuperpoweredRecorder)

Problem i'm facing is that the Recorded file size is too large.
The file size for 2 min recording is 22 MB

Please guide me how can i reduce this file size.

Comment: Select an audio format with less precision and possibly with a lossy compression. If you use a sampling frequency of 44100 Hz (`samplerate` in the library), 2 channels and 16 bits per sample it'll take double the space than if you use a sampling frequency of 22050 Hz or 1 channel or 8 bits etc.

Comment: If i use sample rate of 22050 Hz then it distorted the audio and size is again too large for a small recording.

Comment: I was speaking about the math behind how much space it requires uncompressed:

2 minutes of uncompressed CD quality audio: 44100 samples/second * 2 channels * 16 bits (2 bytes) * 120 seconds (2 minutes) = 21168000 bytes (21.16 MB). 

How is it distorted? Clipping? Playback makes it sound like chipmunks? Something else? You will need to check what combinations the library can handle and what compression algorithms it supports.